# Change registered component in bootstrap period in Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs

Consider the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>

  <main></main>

  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
window.name = "NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!";

angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp')
.component('main', {
  controller: function () {
    this.greeting = 'World';
  },
  template: '<h1>Hello {{ $ctrl.greeting }} from main</h1>'
});

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);

  // Customizing comes here
  // Should change the template to "Hello World from custom main"

  angular.resumeBootstrap();
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/xftcWVXdFslptTGJiNM7?p=preview

I have a base application and a custom "slot" on the server side, where it is possible to insert code between `angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);` and `angular.resumeBootstrap();` in  order to add custom logic to the app.

This works fine when adding new modules to the app, for instance.

Is there a way to change already registered components? I basically want to be able to change the signature of the registered component object.

In the mininmal example above and in the plunkr I simply want to change the "template" of the already registered component `main` to something else.

**Example edited:** Added controller and amended plunkr

Comment: this seems like the wrong approach to solve this.  The more standard way to solve this problem would be to use `templateUrl`, set that property to a variable pointing to a specific file, and update the property to point to a file containing the new template when necessary.

Comment: @Claies the template was just for the minimal example. I also want to change the controller when possible - bindings - whatever. I basically want to access the component options object.

Comment: what's the use case here?  why even bother to create a component for encapsulated functionality if you just plan on ripping out the functionality and replacing it with something else anyway?  Seems like that is just going to lead to unmanageable code where you can't trust a component to do what it advertises.

Comment: The use case is - that we have a standard application - where in rare cases we want to be able to alter the standard functionality. Thanks for the advise anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say I haven't seen such use case before. Usually we'd just decorate directives... but here's one scary-looking-hacky-feeling workaround.

Change your script injection logic in a way you inject JSON array containing everything you want to override, having `name` and `obj` pairs, where `name` is component you want to modify and `obj` object contains any properties you want to add or replace.

Something like following.

```
window.name = "NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!";

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);    
myApp.component('main', {
  template: '<h1>Initially nothing to bind :(</h1>'
});

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);

  // Customizing comes here in following format
  var json = [{
    name: 'main',
    obj: {
      controller: function() {
        this.goof = 'Yo!';
      },
      template: '<span>{{ $ctrl.goof }}</span>'
    }
  }];

  // Scary looking override logic !!1
  myApp._invokeQueue.forEach(function(current) { 
    var obj = current[2];
    var name = obj[0];
    var replacement = _.findWhere(json, { name: name });

    if (replacement) {
      for (var key in replacement.obj) {
        obj[1][key] = replacement.obj[key];
      }
    }
    current = obj;
  });

  angular.resumeBootstrap();
});
```

> Yo

Forked plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/XQ1vZM

Comment: Thats it! :D Totally hacky, probably totally worst practice - and totally working!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are trying to achieve, but this is possible :

```
window.name = "NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!";

var elem={template: '<h1>Hello from main</h1>'};

angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp')
.component('main', elem);

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);

  // Customizing comes here
  // Should change the template to "Hello from custom main"
  //angular.module('myApp').component('main').template= '<h1>Hello from Custom main</h1>';
  elem.template = '<h1>Hello from Custom main</h1>';
  angular.resumeBootstrap();
});
```

Comment: The template was just to illustrate the example. My goal is to change the component object - after it has been registered.